# Need help. This code removes everything except at index 0

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

The code below works for removing a object from the singly linked list, except at index of 0. What do I need to change?

```
Node<E> current = head;
int currentIndex = 0;

while (current.next != null) {
    if ((currentIndex + 1) == index) {
        Node<E> newNext = current.next.next;
        current.setNext(newNext);
        size--;
        return true;
    }
    current = current.next;
    currentIndex++;
}
```

Comment: Naive solution: check whether `index == 0` first thing and act upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Condition `(currentIndex + 1 == index)` will be false for index 0.
You can check if index equals 0 and move head in this case:

```
if (index == 0) {
   head = head.next;
   size--;
   return true;
}
```